# D3.js Sequence Sunburst, change data on click

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I'm trying to change the data of the Sequence Sunburst found here:
http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426

I want it to change to a new dataset (csv, or json) when I click a button.

I tried reading a new csv, and calling `createVisualization(json);`:

```
$('.toggle-data').click( function() {
  d3.text("../csv/new-data.csv", function(text) {
    var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
    var json = buildHierarchy(csv);
    createVisualization(json);
  });
});
```

I also tried calling `createVisualization(json);`directly with an updated json.

In both ways I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__data__' of null`
Which refers to this line of code: `totalSize = path.node().__data__.value;`

I also tried removing the old svg before creating the new one, but that didn't change anything.

**Question:** How can I change the underlaying data of that sunburst (ideally animating from one dataset to another)?

I didn't manage to make a working **fiddle**, so here is one from another thread (all the code is in the above link though): http://jsfiddle.net/zbZ3S/ (different data - using json, but should be the same code as the link above)

Comment: I'm wrestling with this identical issue right now - did you ever to manage to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't solve it, but used this angular overhaul of the same sunburst: https://gist.github.com/chrisrzhou/d5bdd8546f64ca0e4366
Use `ng-click="sunburst.selectExample('name_of_your_csv')` to add an click event to any element you want.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I solved this issue,

First,  made create visualization segment parametric:

```
d3.text(inputcsvfile, function(text) {
  var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
  var json = buildHierarchy(csv);
  createVisualization(json);
});
```

And, added this at the beginning of the sequences.js

```
// default sunburst data
var inputcsvfile="olddata.csv";

// function to switch to a new data
function updateData() {
  d3.select("#container").selectAll("path").remove();
  var inputcsvfile="newdata.csv";
  d3.text(inputcsvfile, function(text) {
  var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
  var json = buildHierarchy(csv);
  createVisualization(json);
});
};
```

Do not forget to put something to trigger `updateData()`

In my case, I added a button to the main html file as:

```
<div id="mybuttons">
    <input name="updateButton1" 
           type="button" 
           value="Change data" 
           onclick="updateData()" />
</div>
```

Comment: d3.select("#container").selectAll("path").remove(); did it for me

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and the problem is that the program fail get the totalsize of entries. If you can calculate it another way you can do : 
    `totalSize = XXX ;` with XXX the totalSize to debug it until someone find a real solution.

Answer (score 2):

solve the totalSize by modifying the buildHierarchy like so:

```
function buildHierarchy(csv) {
  var root = {"name": "root", "children": []};
  for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
      var sequence = csv[i][0];
      var size = +csv[i][1];
      if (isNaN(size)) { // e.g. if this is a header row
          continue;
      }
totalSize = totalSize + size;
```

add last line